# Heroku Bandwidth and Space

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

How much traffic bandwidth and disk space does Heroku support for a free app?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Heroku free has a 5 MB database and 1 dyno. A dyno is an instance of your application running and responding to requests.
In addition, there is a 100 MB limit of your slug, this includes all gems you use.
Heroku has a soft bandwidth limit of 2TB per month. More details here - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/limits#network-bandwidth

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really think Heroku would be a cool place to host my web apps.

Comment: Yes, it is awesome, and there are many ways to get more out of it too. For instance you can use something like the [asset_sync](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync) gem to make your app even leaner and more responsive. Try out the caching options too.