# How big is a Heroku diskspace in free plan?

Tags: heroku, bandwidth, diskspace

I found this answer about Heroku free plan disk space
[Heroku Bandwidth and Space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530216/heroku-bandwidth-and-space).
But this is in 2011, I dont know if it's still accurate so far.

Besides that, this Heroku Support's response on this post
[Heroku free account limited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536326/heroku-free-account-limited) (the second answer) made me confused too.
Does that mean the free plan disk space is up to 1GB.

Can anyone help me with this, any response will be so appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should have Heroku CLI installed on your machine. Then try:

```sh
heroku run bash -a=YOUR-APP-NAME
~ $ df -h /app
```

In my case, it shows:

```sh
Filesystem              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/evg0-evol0  501G  201G  275G  43% /app
```

Afa I understand, this is a shared space (no way my app could use 201G of space) so take it with a grain of salt. Be aware that you cannot persist your data on a Free Dyno as it will go to sleep (is cleared) every day.

Comment: yeah I have installed and tried these commands, but Im still a bit confused about the size of my app shown after my CLI command run. Like I screwed up the whole homepage of Heroku but I didn't find any exact specifications about disk space for a free plan

Comment: Maybe disk space doesn't matter that much since our apps are loaded into memory, and force restarted when they reach a certain size.

Answer (score 1):

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/limits#dyno-memory

> **Dynos**
> ***Dyno memory***
> Different dyno sizes offer different amounts of maximum RAM:
>
> - free, hobby and standard-1x have 512 MB
> - standard-2x has 1024 MB
> - performance-m has 2.5 GB
> - performance-l has 14 GB
>
> ***Dyno memory and restarts***
> 512 MB x 2 = 1 GB), the dyno manager will restart your dyno with an
> R15 error.> If the memory size of your dyno keeps growing until it reaches two
> times its quota (for a standard-1x dyno,

Your entire app is loaded into memory. Everything you "write to the filesystem" is also written into memory and thus only temporarily exists.

Once you exceed that your Dyno will be forced to restart.

You can circumvent this by using a third party database server which stores all your data. Then you got no more restarts because your memory won't exceed and your data will be persistent.

Comment: Nice answer. It makes sense for Heroku to manage it this way.